# task scheduler fails to execute job

Tags: windows, server, scheduled-tasks

I have a question regarding the task scheduler on microsoft windows server 2012 R2.

I want the server to execute a exe every day.

When I am logged in to the server with remote desktop I am able to execute it normally.

But when the task scheduler should start it, then I get an error message.

Any idea what the reason could be?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'BouncyCastle.C rypto, Version=1.7.4137.9688, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.7.4137.9688, Culture=neutral, PublicK
>   eyToken=a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load f ile or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\system32\BouncyCastle.1.7.0\lib\Net40-Client
>   \BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the  file specified. File name:
>   'file:///C:\Windows\system32\BouncyCastle.1.7.0\lib\Net40-Client\Boun
>   cyCastle.Crypto.dll'    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   cod eBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntro spection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   as semblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMar k& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIn trospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile, Ev idence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
>   AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackM ark)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)    at
>   FollowMe.Aero.PurchaseValidationJob.Program.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(
>   Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)    at
>   System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String a ssemblyFullName)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\M
>   icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure lo gging. To
>   turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fus ion!EnableLog].
>
> at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.ConvertPKCS8ToRSAParamete
>   rs(String pkcs8PrivateKey)    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.FromPrivateKe
>   y(String privateKey) in
>   C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client
>   \Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\ServiceAccountCredential.cs:line
>   91    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateServiceAccountCred
>   entialFromJson(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters) in
>   C:\Users\mdril\
>   Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\Def
>   aultCredentialProvider.cs:line 228    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialF
>   romJson(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters) in
>   C:\Users\mdril\Documen
>   ts\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\DefaultCre
>   dentialProvider.cs:line 181    at
>   FollowMe.Aero.Services.PurchaseValidationServiceJob..ctor(IDapperUnitOfWor
>   k dapperUnitOfWork)    at
>   FollowMe.Aero.PurchaseValidationJob.Program.ValidatePurchases()    at
>   FollowMe.Aero.PurchaseValidationJob.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: File not found perhaps.

Comment: Please don't use images when not absolutely necessary to demonstrate a problem. Error messages are text, and should be posted as text. I could probably answer your question, as I have experience with these sorts of issues, but I can't because I can't see the error message; imgur is blocked by our corporate proxy, so all I see is a link I can't follow.

Comment: well when I execute the exe out of remote desktop file is found. @KenWhite the error message appears "within" the exe, so I am not able to copy it, that's the reason for the image

Comment: OK. Well, if I think about coming back to this question to check on it when I get home in about 7 hours where I can see the image, and if no one has answered it by then, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: The message tells you very clearly what's wrong. It can't load BouncyCastle because it can't find the files. When you execute the exe from the remote desktop, you're not running under the same user account as scheduled tasks do. (And BTW, you can copy/paste directly from that window. Click the icon in the upper left for the system menu, which will have options you can choose from to do so.)

Comment: @KenWhite thank you Ken. Now without image above but text. But honestly I don't get it: With remote desktop I login with Administrator and I let the task also run as administrator. I have "run whether user is logged on or not" on and there the Administrator password stored. Too I have unter "When running the task, use the following user account:" the administrator selected

Comment: @KenWhite any more idea for me here?